# How to click check boxes, put text in text boxes and click buttons using Python 3.x (which does not have the mechanize library)?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a newbie to Python. Started on Python 2.7 but quickly jumped to 3.2. I require a Python script that logs in to a password secure website (already done) and then do some operations such as writing to text box, clicking buttons etc. Life would have been easier with **'mechanize**' I suppose (but it is not there for 3.x). Is there any other way? Please help.

Comment: Use Python 2.x for projects that need external libraries. Most of them just haven't been ported to Python 3.x yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of finding the text box and writing in it, then finding the submit button and clicking in it, you can just submit the finished form instead. There are various tools for browsers like Chrome and Firefox that let you see the fields of the form so you know what you submitted. Then you can replicate that in Python with urllib:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
>>> params = params.encode('utf-8')
>>> f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.musi-cal.com/cgi-bin/query", params)
>>> print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: **Thanx Lennart but I already know the fields of the form but don't know how to use them. Any links will be of great help.**

Comment: @Rahul: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html#examples (and why do you bold your comments? You just look angry.)

Comment: @Lennart-Sorry. I thought bold will make the comment eye-catching (I was anxious for an answer and yes, I was angry..with myself..;)) I think this will work..thanks a lot!..will probable have to try a little more. Still, just one more query. I need to click a submit button on the page and then a Save button that saves the settings. How do I go about that?

Comment: @Rahul: Both those actions probably submit a form. You just need to figure out to what url (=action) it is submitted to, and what field it submits.

Comment: @Lennart-Thanks. I'll try it out. Will probably come back if it doesn't work. (That will be very soon as I need this to work by weekend). Will it be possible to have two actions on the same script?